# How do I reshape my images for NN properly

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, python-3.7, opencv, python

I trained my NN model & saved it using next code:

```
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
import cv2
import numpy as np

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name='img')

x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='mnist_model')
# model.summary()

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784).astype('float32') / 255

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
            metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=64,
                    epochs=5,
                    validation_split=0.2)
test_scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
model.save("myFirstModel.model")
# print('Test loss:', test_scores[0])
# print('Test accuracy:', test_scores[1])
# print("-"*20)
```

So as you could see training image sizes are `28x28` pixels. But when I load my trained model and trying to predict the value on my custom image (`1620x2160` pixels) that is taken from my phone it returns me an error:

```
model = keras.models.load_model('myFirstModel.model')
model.summary()

img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Horseman.mini/Desktop/7.jpg', 0) # it is a picture of number 7
# img = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28)) # if I use this - error 1 occures
img = np.resize(img, (-1, 28, 28, 1)) # if I use this - error 2 occures
img_array = np.asarray(img)
Xnew = np.array([img_array])
# make a prediction
ynew = model.predict(Xnew)
result = np.argmax(ynew, axis=1)
print("predicted : ", result)
```

`error 1`

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784 but received input with shape [None, 28, 28]
```

`error 2`

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3498416 into shape (28,28,1)
```

**Quesitons**

1. How do I reshape my image properly for this model to work without such an error.
2. What should I do for predicting numbers (in this case) from the images with different `w x h` sizes, not only images with the size of 28x28 pixels?

**EDIT 1**

Tried to change w and h to 784, now no previous error, except a new one, probably the next is because of that one error. But it returns me, that my `7.jpg` number is 2. I changed to `0.jpg` (that is 0), and predicted result is still 2. So the output is wrong by some reason..

```
model = keras.models.load_model('myFirstModel.model')
model.summary()

img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Horseman.mini/Desktop/7.jpg', 0)
img = cv2.resize(img, (784, 784))

img_array = np.asarray(img)

Xnew = np.array([img_array])
ynew = model.predict(Xnew)
result = np.argmax(ynew)
print("predicted : ", result) # always result is 2
```

`output`

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 784) for input Tensor("img:0", shape=(None, 784), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 784, 784).
predicted :  2
```

Answer (score 0):

In you model you specified the input_shape=784 so you need the image that you want to predict to also be of dimension 784 not 28 X 28 so resize it to 784. You model is trained for images with a dimension of 784 pixels so regardless of the original image's dimensions you must reshape  it to 784 pixels before using it. Just a word of caution for the future. You are reading in images with cv2 but since they are grey scale images that is ok. However if they were color images remember that cv2 reads the image as a bgr image not rgb. So if you had trained on rgb images but read in bgr images for predictions it will not give accurate results. You must convert the images to rgb using

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Made this mistake myself recently and it is easy to forget to convert the image

Comment: Do not clearly understand how should I specify it. When I `cv2.resize(img, (784))` it returns me `function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`. `cv2.resize(img, (784,))` doesnot work too. When I `img = cv2.resize(img, (784, img.shape[0]))` it says `WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 784) for input Tensor("img:0", shape=(None, 784), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1600, 784)` How exactly should I do it?